# Sort articles by Facebook likes and Twitter tweets

Tags: facebook-graph-api, twitter, facebook-like

Lets say I have a website with ~1 000 000 articles. Each of them has Like and Tweet button. I can use Facebook's and Twitter's APIs to get the sum of likes and tweets for each individual article.

However, I want to sort ALL the articles by this sum in more or less real time. Not sure if this is possible, because I must make two API calls for each of the articles, resulting in 2 000 000 requests each time I want to update this sum.

So, is there a way to do this? Can you confirm that there is not? I would be happy if it updates once an hour, or it somehow updates only the most recent articles.. Hm. I have no good ideas about it.

Answer (score 2):

There's an interesting article at http://blog.newswhip.com/index.php/2014/01/what-is-social-velocity about this topic.

You'll have a hard time to implement this for 1.000.000 articles I guess. You can optimize calls to Facebook by using multiple URLs at once in the `/?ids={url}` endpoint:

```
/?fields=id,shares&ids=http://www.google.com,http://www.facebook.com
```

will give you

```
{
  "http://www.google.com": {
    "id": "http://www.google.com", 
    "shares": 10053803
  }, 
  "http://www.facebook.com": {
    "id": "http://www.facebook.com", 
    "shares": 16690062
  }
}
```

but I think you'll head in rate limiting by the Facebook API if you call the API that often. Add an App Access Token to your calls should make this better, but you'll need to try it yourself. Result caching should also a way to limit the call number.